# Learn Python The Hard Way: Exercise 46 Install Module

Tags: python, python-2.7

The Required Quiz in [Exercise 46](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html)  asks readers to install a module/package.  I don't understand if the module and script I created are suited for the exercise and I don't understand the proper way of calling the package once I have installed it. Any insights about the dynamics of the script and module interaction or their purpose would be appreciated as well.

Here is the directory structure: [image]

setup.py:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'description': 'My Project',
    'author': 'John',
    'url': 'URL to get it at.',
    'download_url': 'Where to download it.',
    'author_email': 'john@',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': ['ex47package'],
    'scripts': ['bin/ex47_script.py'],
    'name': 'ex47'
}

setup(**config)
```

ex47_module.py:

```
def explainIt():
    print "root_package"
    print "\tsetup.py"
    print "\tbin: a standard place to put scripts that are run on the command line, \
not a place to put modules."
    print"\t\tmyScipt.py"

    print "\tdocs"
    print "\ttests"
    print "\t\t__init__.py : tells Python that this directory is indeed a package; can be blank"
    print "\tmyPackage: the folder containing your Python code;\
should be the name you specify to 'packages' below"
    print "\t\t__init__.py : tells Python that this directory is indeed a package; can be blank"
    print "\t\tmyModule.py : your actual code; name doesn't matter"
    print "\nto install: python setup.py install"
    print "to uninstall: pip uninstall (name from setup.py)"
```

ex47_script.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "This is the script in the bin directory"
xxx = raw_input("Enter some stuff to print: ")
print xxx
```

After I ran python setup.py install   ex47_script.py was installed in

> /usr/local/share/python

and ex47-0.1-py2.7.egg was installed in

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages